# Ordering in the ManyRelatedManager object

Tags: django, django-models

I have a general question regarding the ordering in
the ManyRelatedManager object.  For example,
There are two classes in my model:  one is
called Book for books and another is Author for authors.

A many-to-many field is defined  in class Book
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)

In database, the many-to-many relationship
is described in an additional table book_author
with three columns: (id, book_id, author_id)

Now for a Book object b, both b.authors.all() and b.authors.iterator()
are sorted in the order of book_author.author_id.
But what I want is to retrieve the authors of b
in the order of book_author.id because this is
the right order of the authors.

Any solutions? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you want different Author ordering based on book, I would suggest using a `ManyToMany` field and specifying the `through` attribute as described here:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

If your `through` model defines an ordering column, you could query the `through` model directly, e.g.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField('Author', through='BookAuthor')

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class BookAuthor(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    ordering = models.IntegerField()
```

You can now query the `through` model directly if you'd like:

```
b = Book.objects.get(pk=1)
BookAuthor.objects.filter(book=b).order_by('ordering')
```

You can also add the `Meta` `ordering` to add the `order_by` whenever querying this model...

```
class BookAuthor(models.Model):
    # ...
    ordering = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('ordering',)
```

Now you can remove extra `.order_by` clause, as Django will add this itself.

```
b = Book.objects.get(pk=1)
BookAuthor.objects.filter(book=b)
```

Note: Even with a `through` model and a `Meta` `ordering`, Django will not add the `.order_by` when querying one side or the other, e.g. the following will not have the `ORDER BY` SQL added:

```
b = Book.objects.get(pk=1)
b.authors.all() # Not ordered
```

Comment: That last note deserves reiterating: I thought that adding a `through` model implementing ordering would allow my `all()` calls to magically start sorting themselves. Alas, lots of code needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The "authors" attribute of a Book instance is a manager, so manager method order_by() will work on it:

```
book = Book.objects.get(id=1)
authors = book.authors.order_by('-last_name')
```

(assuming you have a "last_name" field on Author)

Comment: I believe you can also define a default ordering on Authors, which should be in effect when you query Authors through an of the managers. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering

Comment: Note that the ordering I want does NOT depend on the attributes of authors. Actually for a same list of authors, they may have different ordering depending on what the book is. Say, if Author A and Author B have co-authored two books. In one book, A is the first book while in another book, B is the first author. Then what I want is that for book 1, the order of authors is A and B, while for book 2, the order of authors is B and A.